# MySQL Workbench Inserting values to tables based on foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I built my model on MySQL Workbench then forward engineered the model to a schema. From there I added values to the tables from a main dataset. So at this point I have added all of the data from the large dataset to the schema one time. What do I do to have the tables with foreign keys automatically pull the data from the referenced table? I shouldn't have to insert the same data twice right?

Comment: Are you asking for JOINs?

Comment: I guess it is a join but I already have a table with some data on it and nulls where the foreign key data should be. And for many to many relationships, the joining dependent table has no data at all. Is there a way to have these tables go to the reference table and populate?